# The existing data required by the data writer could not be found

Tags: xenforo

On my page for an add-on i am creating works perfectly well unless i try to update an existing row. `public function actionUpdate()
{

```
$visitor = XenForo_Visitor::getInstance();
     $userName = $visitor['username'];
//Get the text that user wrote in the text box
$text3 = $this->_input->filterSingle('simple_text2', XenForo_Input::STRING);
$text4 = $this->_input->filterSingle('simple_text3', XenForo_Input::STRING);

//Create a instance of our DataWriter
$dwSimpleText = XenForo_DataWriter::create('MinecraftAdder_DataWriter_MinecraftAdder');

//Set the field with the data we filtered
$dwSimpleText->setExistingData('Name');
$dwSimpleText->set('Name', $text3);
$dwSimpleText->setExistingData('Rank');
$dwSimpleText->set('Rank', XenForo_Visitor::getUserId());
$dwSimpleText->setExistingData('UUID');
$dwSimpleText->set('UUID', $text4);
$dwSimpleText->setExistingData('UserID');
$dwSimpleText->set('UserID', $userName);
//Save in the database, please!
$dwSimpleText->save();

//Send a response to the user, so he know that everything went fine with this action
return $this->responseRedirect(
            XenForo_ControllerResponse_Redirect::SUCCESS,
            $this->getDynamicRedirect()
        );
```

}`
I get the error The existing data required by the data writer could not be found. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[My Addon page](http://msnetwork.cf/debug/index.php?pages/MinecraftAdder/)

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `setExistingData` is incorrect. That function must be given one of these two values:

- The value of the Primary Key column(s) for the row you want to update
- An array with all the data for the row you want to update

So in your case, seeing as you don't select the row in advance, you'd use option 1. Assuming `UserID` is your Primary Key column, your code would be:

```
public function actionUpdate() {
    $visitor = XenForo_Visitor::getInstance();
    $userName = $visitor['username'];
    //Get the text that user wrote in the text box
    $text3 = $this->_input->filterSingle('simple_text2', XenForo_Input::STRING);
    $text4 = $this->_input->filterSingle('simple_text3', XenForo_Input::STRING);

    //Create a instance of our DataWriter
    $dwSimpleText = XenForo_DataWriter::create('MinecraftAdder_DataWriter_MinecraftAdder');

    //Set the field with the data we filtered
    $dwSimpleText->setExistingData($userName);
    $dwSimpleText->set('Name', $text3);
    $dwSimpleText->set('Rank', XenForo_Visitor::getUserId());
    $dwSimpleText->set('UUID', $text4);
    //Save in the database, please!
    $dwSimpleText->save();

    //Send a response to the user, so he know that everything went fine with this action
    return $this->responseRedirect(
        XenForo_ControllerResponse_Redirect::SUCCESS,
        $this->getDynamicRedirect()
    );
}
```

Some other tips:

- If this `actionUpdate` may be accessed through a form only, you should add `$this->_assertPostOnly();` on the top of the function to make sure the request was a POST request.
- You may want to check if the Visitor's `user_id` is `0` so you don't save the information of guests. (Unless that's what you want of course)